# Django: how to display form errors for each model object

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

views.py

```
def add_phone(request):
    user=request.user
    try:
        phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except:
        phone = None
    save_msg = ''
    form_error = False
    phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':request.user})
    phoneForm = PhoneForm(instance=phone)
    if request.method=='POST':
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST,instance=phone)    
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.user = user
            phone.save()
            save_msg = "Your details have been saved"


    return render_to_response('incident/add_phone.html',
    {
    'about_menu': True,
    'PhoneForm' :phoneForm,
    'save_msg':save_msg,
    'form_error':form_error,
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emergency = forms.CharField(required=True)
    emergency_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
        fields = ['name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']


def clean(self):
    name1 = self.cleaned_data.get("name1", None)
    number1 = self.cleaned_data.get("number1", None)
    name2 = self.cleaned_data.get("name2", None)
    number2 = self.cleaned_data.get("number2", None)
    name3 = self.cleaned_data.get("name3", None)
    number3 = self.cleaned_data.get("number3", None)
    if name1 and not number1:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required")
    if number1 and not name1:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required")
    if name2 and not number2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required")
    if number2 and not name2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required")
    if name3 and not number3:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required")
    if number3 and not name3:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required")

    return self.cleaned_data
```

template.html

```
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="phone">

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h1 align="left">Call - default telephone numbers</h1>        </td>

                <tr>
                    <td>Person or area</td>
                    <td>Phone number</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ PhoneForm.name1 }}{{ PhoneForm.name1.errors }}</td>
                    <td>{{ PhoneForm.number1 }}{{ PhoneForm.number1.errors }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ PhoneForm.name2 }}{{ PhoneForm.name2.errors }}</td>
                    <td>{{ PhoneForm.number2 }}{{ PhoneForm.number2.errors }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.name3}}{{ PhoneForm.name3.errors }}</td>
                    <td>{{PhoneForm.number3}}{{ PhoneForm.number3.errors }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Emergency</td><td>Phone number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ PhoneForm.emergency }}{{ PhoneForm.emergency.errors }}</td>
                    <td>{{ PhoneForm.emergency_number }}{{ PhoneForm.emergency_number.errors }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> <p style=margin-top:2cm;>{% include "buttons/save.html" %}</p></td></tr>

            </table></form>
```

It is not throwing the individual error message of form validation.I am using PhoneForm and for individual field,individual error message should occur.I checked it,i am not able to find what i missing.It may be silly Need  help to fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you're not running checks for individual fields. You're defining the overall `clean()` method, and throwing general errors - all you say is "This field is required", without defining what field you're talking about. I don't know how you expect Django to know.

The normal thing to do is to override the specific field clean methods, eg `clean_number1` etc. You're correct not to do that because each field depends on another field, so `clean()` is the right place.

But as the documentation shows, you can [inject field-specific errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) from the general `clean` method:

```
self._errors['number1'] = self.error_class(['This field is required'])
del self.cleaned_data['number1']
```

Comment: I previously don't think about that.Thanks Daniel!